# Windows Form stuck while executing cmd.exe

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line

I'm trying to execute a command via cmd, but when the program runs, the entire window is stuck and not responsive. Can't press buttons, can't close the form etc.
This is the code for execution:

```
    private void buttonStartTests_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String command = @"/c perl script.pl";
        ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        cmdsi.Arguments = command;
        cmdsi.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdsi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmdsi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        cmdsi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);

        String outstr;

        while ((outstr = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            this.richTextBoxTestOutput.Text += (outstr + "\n");
            this.richTextBoxTestOutput.Update();
        }

        //Wait for process to finish
        //cmd.WaitForExit();

        cmd.Close();
    }
```

The question is: how do I prevent it from getting stuck?

Edit: The form becomes responsive again once the command is finished (just to make things clear).

Comment: You may use .net 4.5 features like `await` and `async`

Comment: as is, it is not asynchronous, so it executes all the code in order and the rest of the app waits on it.  The window becomes unresponsive when this event handler is triggered and never returns to a responsive state because whatever is going on in this event never completes.  You can try setting a break point on the event, then stepping into the code to see where its hanging up.

Comment: @user116969 if my answer helped you, please consider chosing it as the correct answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should consider starting cmd in a background process -

i think the way you do it, the mainthread will be unresponsive until cmd delivers a return..?
So it is blocking the mainthread.

Backgroundworker might be an option.

Comment: yeah, exactly what I was just typing.  Its probably on the main thread, and would work better on a background worker or its own thread.  Its not immediately clear to me however why its not becoming responsive again when the command completes... unless it never completes...